# Azure Api management with Oauth - Without a client app registration

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

I currently have an API that I am opening up to our business partners to call, and I want it secured with OAuth.
I've set up an Azure API management (consumption plan right now) that points to our API in azure.
I can call it and get valid results in the test console.

So I was following the Microsoft documentation for this, and it had me :

- Register my backend API in app registrations;
- Register a client app in app registrations;
- In azure AD grand the permissions for this client app;
- Configure the APIM with a validate-jwt policy.

So now my APIM is returning a 403 as expected.
My question is this. I do not know the clients that will be using this API. Or rather, do I HAVE to register a client app registration? Or can I leave that part out, and just provide the URLS that I have for the OAUTH side, which are like :

https://login.microsoftonline.com/GUID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize

https://login.microsoftonline.com/GUID/oauth2/v2.0/token

I am very new to Oauth and APIM, so I am not even sure how all this works.
But it seems odd that I am registering an app for a client, when I have no information on them or how they are calling my API.
I kinda get that I need to know who is requesting the token and authorizing. But the clients will be using a javascript snippet that we give them to embed on their site, so I dont really know what their site is like, what their URL is or anything.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The client registration is what represents the entity (web app, mobile app, etc.) that requests for tokens from Azure AD for your API.

The docs walk you through a process where the developer portal is registered as the client.

The snippet in your case would also require a Client ID (of an app) to fetch the token with. For this, you would have to register a new app registration and share the Client ID as part of the snippet.